# Where are my c# templates?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I installed the Visual Studio 2015 on my windows 10 OS. After the installation, I could choose between a bunch of c# templates when I wanted to create a new project. Ok, I succesfully made my project, there wasn't any problem at all. On the next day, I wanted to create another c# project, but this was all what I saw
: http://postimg.org/image/iim0sem09/ . 
I could choose from 3 templates only.
I tried to re-install the VS2015, didn't help, after that I tried this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms247116(v=vs.100).aspx
, did not work. After all I re-installed the windows 10 then downloaded the VS2015 , but that did not help too...
My biggest problem is that I can't make c# windows form application & console application.

What should I do ? Can I import the templates? (Sorry for bad English)

Comment: are you sure you installed them in the VS2015 setup?

Comment: Well, after a whole day I finally figured out what was my problem.

I usually ran the Visual Studio Blend API and not the Visual Studio..
I know I was regardless...but the Visual Studio Blend was the only one thing I could see in the Start menu. After the installation it lauched the VS Blend automatically... Anway thank you for your time and as always sorry for my bad English.